# Error during copy and paste text from pc to Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

About 2 months ago I was able to copy text from my pc clipboard and paste it into an app running on Android Studio emulator simply doing ctrl+c on pc and pasting it into a TextView. Now I'm using the new version Android Studio 3.0 and I can't do that. When I copy text from my pc the emulator ignore it: the clipboard of my pc and the one of the emulator don't communicate. Maybe with the new update I have to change something in the settings of the emulator but I have found nothing about it (except for the option "Enable clipboard sharing" that is allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm issue. There is a bug report about this [on issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71417569). I confirm solution of toggling switch "Enable clipboard sharing" in emulator -> three dots -> settings. If you disable and re-enable switch, clipboard sharing works again.

Comment: This did the trick for me as well. Very obscure and frustrating issue

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

The solution that always works for me is to Restart Android directly from the emulator or the other option is from the Device Manager in Android Studio with the option "Cold boot now".

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, as of Android Studio 3. Here is a quick-fix.

1. Start Android Studio
2. Start the AVD
3. Click the three dots, down on the sidebar
4. Click Settings
5. Toggle the switch "Enable clipboard sharing".
6. C&P should work again

Tested with: Android Studio 3.0.1, AVD API Version 26

[image]

Comment: The action menu does not have a "3 dots" button. I am using `Android Studio 4.2.2` and my Android emulator runs `Pixel 4 API 24`.

Answer (score 2):

@AlfaSpider answer is correct , after enabling the setting still issue exist , please do **wipe data** option from Device Manager window