# How to disable Clipboard editor overlay Android Emulator API 33?

Tags: android, android-12, clipboardmanager

How can i disable **Clipboard editor overlay,** that is enabled by default in Android Emulator API 33?.
It is very annoying while debugging apps.It always popup over my debugging apps, and i have to close this every time to do something in my debugging app.

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason your app is putting class definitions in the system clipboard in the first place?

Comment: It will show when `getPrimaryClip()` is being called and there seems to be no way to control that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sorry for the confusion!!, My question was about android emulator. I updated my question . Those class definitions are from my clipboard , that i copied from android studio while coding..

Comment: @Martin Zeitler Sorry !!!, i forgot to mention that, the question was about android emulator and the screenshot also was also from my emulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable clipboard overlay:

```
adb shell device_config put systemui clipboard_overlay_enabled false
adb reboot
```

We need reboot since SystemUI read the config too earlier.

Comment: Does this work on real device? Is root required for this?

Comment: I tried these _adb_ commands today on a **Pixel 6A (Android 13)** device (not rooted or modified in any way) and it didn't work, after reboot, the clipboard overlay continues showing up.

Comment: what's the output of adb shell device_config get systemui clipboard_overlay_enabled

Comment: @EricSu It did work on my Xperia 5 V with Android 13

Comment: Sadly doesn't work in LineageOS 20 either.

Comment: It worked for my Motorola Moto G32 with Android 13.

Comment: … and that crap appeared again after few restarts.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might not be helpful but I also getting annoyed by this. I can't click bottom nav without sliding clipboard pop up. But you can disable clipboard sharing access from emulator setting.

1. Start Android Studio
2. Start the AVD
3. Click the three dots, down on the sidebar
4. Click Settings Toggle the switch "Enable clipboard sharing".

[Source solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48439945/15225266)

Comment: Hi, This setting is not available in the current stable version of Android studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch1. They removed, and may be available in future versions

Comment: Upps... My bad. It seems right now the only solution is downgrade android emulator image to API 32